# Modal not going under the navigation bar when using TabNavigator on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I want to display a fullscreen Modal that goes under the status bar and the navigation bar. When not in a TabNavigator, this is working well on both Android and iOS. For example, it works well in a StackNavigator.

However, when I put the Modal in TabNavigator, the Modal stops going under the navigation bar on Android only.

Because it is working in StackNavigator, I assume that my configuration for Android is correct, and that the problem comes somewhere else, maybe in the TabNavigator configuration? But I can't figure it out.

Just to be clear, I am talking about going under the navigation bar, not about going over the tab bar, which seems to be a common issue out there, but works well for me.